# Programmatically adding default content via URL to document set

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document, pnp-powershell, document-set

I´m trying to programmatically add default content to a document set via powershell in SharePoint Online.
The thing is, that I only find examples where the files are given/uploaded, I would need a solution/example how to give the default content template via a URL.

Is that possible? (I guess so) Because you can also only upload templates to document libraries via GUI but programmatically you can set a URL for the template.
If it`s not possible, does anyone know, where the uploaded templates for the document sets are saved?

Cheers and many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, the only way to change document set default contents is go to Site settings -> Site content types -> Document set -> Document Set settings.

Or you could refer [this article](https://m365solutions.blog/adding-default-document-content-for-a-document-set-using-pnp-powershell/) to use PnP PowerShell to add default contents in the document set.